Return Results if No Record is Found in Data
The goal is to show the number of orders in different buckets (0-100, 101-400, 401-800, 801-1000, and 1001 and above). However, there are no orders of 1001 and above, but we still need to show that bucket as have 0 orders. I can't figure out how to show that row. I am using the Orcale SQL builder.
Below is the coding I have right now. I am able to show the buckets that have orders in them, but I can't get the line showing 0 orders of 1001 and above. Please help.
SELECT "Bucket", COUNT(*) AS "Order Count"
FROM
(
SELECT CASE
    WHEN O.QuantityShares <= 100 THEN '1. 0-100'
    WHEN O.QuantityShares <= 400 THEN '2. 101-400'
    WHEN O.QuantityShares <= 800 THEN '3. 401-800'
    WHEN O.QuantityShares <= 1000 THEN '4. 801-1000'
    ELSE '5. 1001 and Above'
  END AS "Bucket"
FROM OrderTransactions O
)
GROUP BY "Bucket"
ORDER BY "Bucket" ASC
/


You can define the buckets and use a left outer join to the data to count how many match; because it's an outer join it will still show data for buckets with no matches.
For example:
WITH Buckets (Bucket) AS
(
  SELECT '1. 0-100' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '2. 101-400' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '3. 401-800' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '4. 801-1000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '5. 1001 and Above' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT B.Bucket AS "Bucket", COUNT(O.Bucket) AS "Order Count"
FROM Buckets B
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT CASE
      WHEN O.QuantityShares <= 100 THEN '1. 0-100'
      WHEN O.QuantityShares <= 400 THEN '2. 101-400'
      WHEN O.QuantityShares <= 800 THEN '3. 401-800'
      WHEN O.QuantityShares <= 1000 THEN '4. 801-1000'
      ELSE '5. 1001 and Above'
    END AS Bucket
  FROM OrderTransactions O
) O
ON O.Bucket = B.Bucket
GROUP BY B.Bucket
ORDER BY B.Bucket ASC
/

Or to avoid repeating the labels, use a synthetic 'key' as the join instead:
WITH Buckets (Bucket, Label) AS
(
  SELECT 1, '1. 0-100' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2. 101-400' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '3. 401-800' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, '4. 801-1000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, '5. 1001 and Above' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT B.Label AS "Bucket", COUNT(O.Bucket) AS "Order Count"
FROM Buckets B
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT CASE
      WHEN O.QuantityShares <= 100 THEN 1
      WHEN O.QuantityShares <= 400 THEN 2
      WHEN O.QuantityShares <= 800 THEN 3
      WHEN O.QuantityShares <= 1000 THEN 4
      ELSE 5
    END AS Bucket
  FROM OrderTransactions O
) O
ON O.Bucket = B.Bucket
GROUP BY B.Bucket, B.Label
ORDER BY B.Bucket ASC
/

fiddle
